# OpenCV construct range of size 1

Tags: c++, opencv

In the following code, is there a better way to go about constructing the singleton ranges `cv::Range(i, i+1)` and `cv::Range(j, j+1)`?  I would expect there to exist somewhere in OpenCV a function that creates a singleton range, e.g. just a constructor `cv::Range(i)` equivalent to `cv::Range(i, i+1)`.

```
const int sizeA[] = { 100, 100, 100 };
cv::Mat matrix(3, sizeA, cv::DataType<int>::type);

// get submatrix (i, j, :)
int i = 8;
int j = 15;
const cv::Range ranges = { cv::Range(i, i+1), cv::Range(j, j+1), cv::Range::all() };
cv::Mat submatrix = matrix(ranges);
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't indicate a function to do this, but it's trivial to implement your own.

Comment: Obviously it's trivial to implement my own... The question was whether there was an existing function hidden somewhere in OpenCV. I'm assuming there isn't, and I'm of course tentatively using my own trivial implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into OpenCV to do this. Simply write `cv::Range(i, i+1)` everywhere or write your own helper function.